# CSS Transition with a table cell width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I trying to make a horizontal accordion, but I can't figure out how do I get the "cells" to unwrap smoothly. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vf1z1ebp/4/

Transition clearly works with the background and font color upon hover, but the width just jumps instantly. I thought it might be because the other three cells have auto width, but that doesn't seem to be the problem as this one doesn't work either: https://jsfiddle.net/vf1z1ebp/5/

```css
#matrix {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.item {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 35px;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s;
  -moz-transition: all 3s;
  -o-transition: all 3s;
  transition: all 3s;
}

.item:hover {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table id="matrix">
  <tr>

    <td class="item">
      One
    </td>

    <td class="item">
      Two
    </td>

    <td class="item">
      Three
    </td>

    <td class="item">
      Four
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For transition to work you have to give a `width` to the element like this.Transitions can only animate across numerical values

```css
#matrix {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.item {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 35px;
  width: 10%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.item:hover {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table id="matrix">
  <tr>

    <td class="item">
      One
    </td>

    <td class="item">
      Two
    </td>

    <td class="item">
      Three
    </td>

    <td class="item">
      Four
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It works: https://jsfiddle.net/vf1z1ebp/14/ ! So  in order to transition correctly, not only the target value has to be specified, but the starting value as well, right? Thanks for your answer! Is it not somehow possible to get rid of the twitching tho?

Comment: @MalejPštros Best option will be to decrease the time and use a timing function you can change it to linear if you want

Comment: Your td width is hard-coded. It is not dynamic. There is nothing extraordinary in your approach, pretty common.

Comment: @Green What do you mean by hardcore i just updated his code to make it animate as he wanted

Comment: Can you transition actual width without hardcoding width value? For example, when cell's text gets replaces by longer text table will try stretch column to fit it. Is there a way to animate this?