# Is it possible to use CSS transition of width on a column depending on the content of a table cell?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-transitions

My goal is to have a table with headers that expand smoothly (using CSS `transition`) to the full text width of the cell content when you hover over the header cell. My current approach is to have a fixed `ch` width of the container of the text in the header cell and let that container expand to `100%` or a fixed px width when you hover it.

The actual reason for doing this is that the table I am working with have very limited available width and this would be a way to shrink the overall width without removing columns. This way of displaying the full text would be a fancier way of showing the full text in the header compared to having a tool tip pop up when you hover it.

I expect the width of all cells in the column to make a smooth transition to the new heading cell width. Currently the only element that expands smoothly is the expanding container in the header cell that is hovered and the actual cells in the column expand with no transition to the new calculated width.

I have seen other examples (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290429/css-transition-with-tables) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32333649/css-transition-with-a-table-cell-width)) where people animate the width but no one seem to animate the width to a dynamic width set by the content of a heading cell. Is this possible without js?

Working example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: width 250ms ease-out;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th:hover .th-title {
  width: 100% !important;
}

th,
td {
  width: 100%;
}

.th-title {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#th-domain {
  width: 3ch;
}

#th-name {
  width: 4ch;
}

#th-key {
  width: 3ch;
}

#th-protocol {
  width: 4ch;
}

#th-ip {
  width: 7ch;
}

/* Styling code */
th,
td {
  font-family: Monaco, monospace;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

th {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1d7490;
  height: 32px;
}

tbody>tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div id="th-domain" class="th-title">DomainDomain</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div id="th-name" class="th-title">NameName</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div id="th-key" class="th-title">KeyKey</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div id="th-protocol" class="th-title">ProtocolProtocol</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div id="th-ip" class="th-title">Last IPLast IP</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Domain1</label></td>
      <td><label>Name1</label></td>
      <td><label>Key1</label></td>
      <td><label>Protocol1</label></td>
      <td><label>IP1</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Domain2</label></td>
      <td><label>Name2</label></td>
      <td><label>Key2</label></td>
      <td><label>Protocol2</label></td>
      <td><label>IP2</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Domain3</label></td>
      <td><label>Name3</label></td>
      <td><label>Key3</label></td>
      <td><label>Protocol3</label></td>
      <td><label>IP3</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Domain4</label></td>
      <td><label>Name4</label></td>
      <td><label>Key4</label></td>
      <td><label>Protocol4</label></td>
      <td><label>IP4</label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit: adjusted width of table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a good way to do it with css but it is quite easy to do with js. I settled on using the mouseenter and mouseleave event to trigger an animation of the width on the target element using the [anime.js](https://animejs.com/) library which is quite easy to use when animating css properties.